# Run Gradle in different Git branch without checking branch out

Tags: java, git, gradle

Is it possible to run gradle on a specific git branch without switching to that branch?

E.g. running gradle on a feature branch while having locally checkout out the main branch.

Comment: I doubt it's possible. Most tools know nothing about branches or commits, they work with files so these files have to be checked out. Do it in a separate [tag:git-worktree], clone or simply a copy of the working tree, then switch to the feature branch.

Comment: It's _not_ possible using a single worktree.... but you can create a new worktree using another branch.... when you are done, remove the worktree.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a place where you store files of that feature version for gradle to work with. So, technically, the answer is no. You can use other folder, or Continuous Integration solution like Jenkins.